# Why the function calls not getting executed?

Tags: c, string, function

```
#include<stdio.h>

void check_alphabets(char array_string[],int n){
    char alphabet_array[n];
    int i,j,val;

    int alphabet_array_counter=0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        val=array_string[i];
        if((val>=65 && val<=90) || (val>=97 && val<=122)){
            alphabet_array[alphabet_array_counter]=array_string[i];
            alphabet_array_counter++;
        }
    }
    for(j=0;j<n;j++){
        printf("%c",alphabet_array[j]);
    }
}

void check_number(char array_string[],int n){
    char number_array[n];
    int i,j,val;
    int number_array_counter=0;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        val=array_string[i];
        if(val>=30 && val<=39){
            number_array[number_array_counter]=array_string[i];
            number_array_counter++;
        }
    }
       for(j=0;j<n;j++){
        printf("%c",number_array[j]);
    }
}

void check_character(char array_string[],int n){
    char character_array[n];
    int i,j,val;
    int character_array_counter=0;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        val=array_string[i];
        if((val>=32 && val<=47) || (val>=58 && val<=64) || (val>=91 && val<=96) || (val>=123 && val<=127)){
            character_array[character_array_counter]=array_string[i];
           character_array_counter++;
        }
    }
    for(j=0;j<n;j++){
        printf("%c",character_array[j]);
    }

}

void main(){
    int size=100;
    char array_string[size];
    printf("Enter string? ");
    scanf("%s",array_string);

    int i=0,count=0;
    while(array_string[i]!='\0'){
        count++;
        i++;
    }
    printf("size is %d",count);

    void check_alphabets(array_string,count);
    void check_number(array_string,count);
    void check_character(array_string,count); 


}
```

I have the above piece of code . I don't know what is wrong with it .No matter what I modify The functions are not getting executed.
I am compiling using gcc in ubuntu 18.
But whenever I try to compile it throws a warning which is

> In function `main`
>   warning:parameter names(without types) in function declaration `void check_alphabets(array_string,count)`

this warning shows with all the calls from main.
I googled but couldn't find any solution.

Comment: Don't use `void` when calling a function. Just `check_alphabets(array_string,count);` is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are not function calls:

```
void check_alphabets(array_string,count);
void check_number(array_string,count);
void check_character(array_string,count);
```

These are declarations.  The return type in front of the function name tells us this is a declaration.  When you call a function, you don't need to say what the return type is:

```
check_alphabets(array_string,count);
check_number(array_string,count);
check_character(array_string,count);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void check_alphabets(array_string,count);
void check_number(array_string,count);
void check_character(array_string,count);
```

these lines are not function calls. YOu mean

```
check_alphabets(array_string,count);
check_number(array_string,count);
check_character(array_string,count);
```

The warning you are getting is because the compiler thinks you are trying to declare a function, but your syntax is an invalid function declaration (argument names without types)

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to learn how to use Markdown to format your code properly. Secondly, you're not calling your functions in `main`, you are only declaring them.

```
void check_alphabets(array_string,count);
void check_number(array_string,count);
void check_character(array_string,count);
```

must become

```
check_alphabets(array_string,count);
check_number(array_string,count);
check_character(array_string,count);
```